# jQuery event triggerred for elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following html ....

```
<INPUT name="debit[]" id=d1 class='Right debit' type="text" value="" /><br/>
<INPUT name="debit[]" id=d2 class='Right debit' type="text" value="" /><br/>
<INPUT name="debit[]" id=d3 class='Right debit' type="text" value="" /><br/>
<INPUT name="debit[]" id=d4 class='Right debit' type="text" value="" /><br/>
<INPUT name="debit[]" id=d5 class='Right debit' type="text" value="" /><br/>

<INPUT name="iDebit[]" id=iDebit type="text" value="" /><br/>
```

and

```
<script>
$("input.debit").keyup(function(){
    var total = sumSizes('debit');
    $("#iDebit").val(total);
});

function sumSizes(calc) {
    var total = 0;
    $('.' + calc).each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).val(), 10) || 0;
    });
   return (total);
}

function addRow(tableID){
    var table    = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row      = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0;i<colCount;i++){
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
        switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type){
        case "text":
        newcell.childNodes[0].value="";
        break;
        case "checkbox":
        newcell.childNodes[0].checked=false;
        break;
        case "radio":
        newcell.childNodes[0].checked=false;
        break;
        case "select-one":
        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex=0;
        break;
    }
    newcell.childNodes[0].id=newcell.childNodes[0].id+rowCount;
}
updateCredit();
updateBalance();
}
</script>
```

What I want is that whenever I change a value in any of the input 
elements, javascript should calculate the 'total' and update input element with id #iDebit.

It is only working for the first INPUT element. How do I fix this to
work for any of the INPUT elements with class=debit?

Comment: Seems to work fine for all inputs. http://liveweave.com/heBOv3

Comment: Your code seems to work correctly as is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f0gzxkmj/)

Comment: your code works fine where is your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/oy6f46e0/

Comment: It is not calculating when I change values in the other input elements other than the first in put element

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for me but my only advice would be to use ID tags for specific notation and maybe that will work better in your browser.